# How to return the first row using ActiveJDBC?

Tags: activejdbc

`ActiveRecord` has methods such as `Entity.first, Entity.last, Entity.first.next` etc (note there are no parameters passed).

Is there a similar construct in activejdbc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is "first": http://javalite.github.io/activejdbc/org/javalite/activejdbc/Model.html#first-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-

, but not others.

You can do this:

```
User.findAll().orderBy("age").limit(1); //--> first
User.findAll().orderBy("age desc").limit(1); //--> last
```

this way you control exactly is returned.

Comment: The only problem of using `findAll()` is that it returns a `list` rather than the instance of the model.

Comment: correct. ActiveJDBC is not a clone or a port of ActiveRecord to Java.  It is a different ORM, inspired by ActiveRecord.